# 36V DC charger with 12V DC charger and multiplier circuit?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, operational-amplifier, charger

Could I use a 12 V DC charger and and a voltage multiplier to achieve 36 volts? Are there any issues I might come across?

Comment: Your current available will decrease by at least a third, probably closer to 40%.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I need a charger for a 36 volt battery pack I made and I'm just not really confident enough to wire a transformer just yet

Answer (score 2):

With a voltage step up of 3x the available current from the output is proportionately decreased by at least a factor of 3, (e.g. I/3).  On top of this the overall efficiency of the step-up system also decreases the available power.  If the output voltage needs to be stable the step-up voltage may even need to be higher than 36V and then regulated back to 36V, creating additional inefficiencies.

With the above you would need to ensure that your available input current meets and exceeds the proportional requirements of the output. This is one issue that users find out the hard way (by continually replacing burned out fuses) when expecting a 12VDC to 120VAC automotive inverter to power medium power AC appliances.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a low ESR reservoir cap or battery ,
then a boost converter of more power than you need at all times,
and cooling requirements to be examined.

Variable Boost  converters are cheap online but unproven reliability.

Answer (score -2):

Since I do not know the wiring of your voltage divider, assuming it has been done so correctly I could tell that the current passing through will go down to a much lesser level.There is power loss and charging your device will take a long time.

1. Try increasing the current
2. Dont let it overheat

Comment: The OP is talking about a boost converter, not a divider.

Comment: @RonBeyer I understand,thx